# Matching columns from a combined column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Sheet which puts the responses in Columns C to E together whilst also combining the responses in AM2 to AO2 into column F. The formulas work separately however the answers do not match up together. Here are the formulas I have so far:

```
=FILTER({'Form responses 1'!C2:E, 'Form responses 1'!B2:B},UPPER('Form responses 1'!G2:G="Alderton Infant School"))


=FILTER({AM2:AM;AN2:AN;AO2:AO}, LEN({AM2:AM;AN2:AN;AO2:AO}))
```

Comment: Please [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output